# Convert raw data to frequencies

Tags: r, charts, dataset, frequency

I'm having a little trouble trying to plot certain graphs with this data set that I have, the data set is similar to:

```
        Year Count        ENSO          NAO
1   1900     5  0.49063600 -0.073333333
2   1901     7 -0.34351300 -0.461666667
3   1902     5  1.43181000 -1.065000000
4   1903     9 -0.48638500  0.335000000
5   1904     5  0.66698600 -0.103333333
6   1905     3  1.12753000 -0.818333333
7   1906     8 -0.59783800 -0.040000000
8   1907     2 -0.43226700  0.111666667
9   1908     8 -0.48319500  0.421666667
10  1909     8 -1.17421000  0.153333333
11  1910     4 -0.68855800 -0.996666667
12  1911     5  0.38084300  0.115000000
13  1912     5 -0.06871800 -0.535000000
```

And what I would like to do is be able to take the "count" column and plot it as a bar chart of the frequencies of each value in "count", however I'm not really sure where to start, all the guides I am looking through are just showing how to plot the data as a bar chart when you already have the relevant frequencies.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this:

```
barplot(table(dat$Count))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
a <- rnorm(1000)
h <- hist(a)
barplot(h$counts, names=h$mids)
```

With your data, you could plot:

```
barplot(df$Count, names=df$Year)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ggplot2` alternative using `geom_bar`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(Count))) + geom_bar() + xlab('Count')
```

[image]